# INSERT Statement in sqlite python with custom type

Tags: python, sqlite

It is true that I'm new to sqlite and maybe I am just asking a very trivial question.

I would like to store some analysis results in a sqlite table directly from my python analysis tool. The results are contained in a custom object (a class) and I though that the [section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-write-adaptable-objects) of sqlite python documentation 'How to adapt custom Python types to SQLite values' would be a starting point for my problem.

Elaborating from that example, I came to this piece of code that is **not working**:

```py
import sqlite3

class Point:
   def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y

   # define a __conform__ method to adapt the type
   def __conform__(self, protocol):
      if protocol == sqlite3.PrepareProtocol:
         return self.x, self.y

connection = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Points (x REAL, y REAL)
   """)
connection.commit()

# the insert query takes two qmark style placeholder and the __conform__ method of Point is 
# actually returning a tuple with two values. 

# attempt passing a tuple with 1 point to the execute method.
cursor.execute("""
   INSERT INTO Points VALUES (?, ?)
   """, (Point(24.2, 22.1),))
# fails with a ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied. 

# attempt to pass a tuple with 1 point to the execute many method.
cursor.executemany("""
   INSERT INTO Points VALUES (?, ?)
   """, (Point(24.2, 22.1),))
# fails with a ProgrammingError: parameters are of unsupported type

# attempt of passing a Point directly
cursor.execute("""
   INSERT INTO Points VALUES (?, ?)
   """, Point(24.2, 22.1))
# fails with a ProgrammingError: parameters are of unsupported type

# attempt to manually adapt the object
cursor.execute("""
   INSERT INTO Points VALUES (?, ?)
   """, Point(24.2, 22.1).__conform__(sqlite3.PrepareProtocol))
# works, but I can't believe that this is the expected behavior!
```

The only difference between my code and the one provided in the documentation (that works) is that my object is providing two values instead of 1.

I have also tried the second approach with the adapter function to be registered, but with the same result. Moreover I have also tried to replace the qmark placeholder with namedplaceholder and swapped from tuple to dictionary in the adapter, but with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for helping me out with this problem!

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach you can take for multi-valued objects is to make the class behave like a sequence type.

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __len__(self):
        return 2
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return (self.x, self.y)[index]
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Point({self.x}, {self.y})'
```

Then you can just pass the `Point` object as the SQL statement's parameter “list”.

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Points VALUES (?, ?)", Point(24.2, 22.1))
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, it does work! I don't understand why the documentation is proposing to use either the __conform__ method or the definition of an adapter function, while this approach seems to be more general and working well.

Comment: @toto: Well, the documentation seems to be assuming that you want your custom type to be represented in the database as *one* object of one of the five basic SQLite types (`NULL`/`None`, `INTEGER`/`int`, `REAL`/`float`, `TEXT`/`str`, or `BLOB`/`bytes`).